# How To Use Kivy's Core Image?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a grid layout and am adding to it some CoreImage widgets that I want to use for displaying pictures. I chose not to use uix.image since CoreImage is faster and I want to swap between a few pictures often.

When I do self.add_widget(CoreImage('Transparent.png')) my program will crash.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/path/to/my/app.py", line 1030, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 798, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "/path/to/my/app.py", line 702, in build
     self.build_grid()
   File "/path/to/my/app.py", line 696, in build_grid
     self.grid.build_self()
   File "/path/to/my/app.py", line 134, in build_self
     self.add_widget(CoreImage('Transparent.png'))
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 80, in add_widget
     size_hint=self._trigger_layout)
   File "_event.pyx", line 436, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind (kivy/_event.c:5429)
 KeyError: 'size_hint'
```

What am I doing wrong? This works fine when I used uix.image.

Comment: Core Image works fine when I add it with kivy lanuage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kivy.core.image.Image` (I assume this is what you mean) is not a widget, you can't use it like this. Use `kivy.uix.image.Image`.

Comment: What is core image used for then? I want to load a image from memory so it's not so slow.

Comment: The kivy.core.image.Image takes care of loading an image from a file (or potentially elsewhere), caching it if necessary, and turning it into an opengl texture that can be used by an Image widget or anything else. The Image widget is quite simple and largely just loads the image with a CoreImage then displays the result, if you're finding it's slow then perhaps there is a different way to make it faster.

Comment: So when I use uix.image to load multiple instances of the same image is core.image already making it faster by having all my image widgets load from the same core.image?

Comment: If they're from the same filename then yes, I think so.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to do the same for showing a bunch of memory-loaded images. Something like this came out:

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage

self.add_widget(Image(texture=CoreImage('Transparent.png').texture))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In case you want to use it in kvlang, use the import like `#:import CoreImage kivy.core.image.Image`, and set `Image: texture: CoreImage('Transparent.png').texture`